# Can not connect to local database with c# System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection, connection-string, mysql-workbench

I have some problems with connecting to my local DB using c# System.Data.SqlClient.

Information:

- DB parameters: Name:`baza` Host:`localhost` Instance:`baza` Port:`3306` Schema:`world`
- My connection string: `@"server=localhost\baza;password=pass;User Id=root;database=world;Persist Security Info=True"`
- using: c#, System.Data.SqlClient, MySQL Workbench
- firewall off
- succesfull conection with JDBC, so server is working

JDBC parameters:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String dbName = "world";
String username = "root";
String pass = "pass";
```

Problem:

- when I use conn.Open(); this happen => (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Tried:

- server=localhost then it gives => error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server
- many other stupid combinations like server=baza
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx
- [ASP.NET beginner question: How to get rid of this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665084/asp-net-beginner-question-how-to-get-rid-of-this-error)
- Connection to freesql.org server also failed

I have no idea what to do... Sth is probably with server name.

EDIT: 
code:

```
string connstr = @"Data Source=localhost\baza;password=qspass;User Id=root;"+
    "Initial Catalog=world;Persist Security Info=True";

Console.WriteLine(connstr);

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conbuild.ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

Console.WriteLine("YO!");
Some more code...
```

Never reached YO! :P

Comment: The System.Data.SqlClient namespace is the.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server, not MySQL.  If you are using MySQL, you will need to use the MySQL ADO.NET driver available here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose I should put my answer in the answer section, rather than a comment :)

I see from your JDBC connection string that you are using MySQL rather than SQL Server.

The System.Data.SqlClient namespace is the.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server, not MySQL.

If you are using MySQL, you will need to use the MySQL ADO.NET driver available here:

[Download Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Comment: I dont get it, im dumb. How use it? I have it already installed... Like using this MySql.Data in my code?

Comment: I can't explain all that to you here, MySQL provide tutorials on how to use it, see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-tutorials.html